# Calculating the distance between specific rows contained in an array in R

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, distance

I'm trying to calculate the distance between specific points contained in an array in R. My data looks like this:

```r
curve_array
, , Frame001.txt

          [,1]      [,2]
 [1,] 30.13947 -16.92239
 [2,] 30.34071 -16.72115
 [3,] 30.53260 -16.52926
 [4,] 30.72348 -16.33496
 [5,] 30.92572 -16.13614
 [6,] 31.13358 -15.95087
 [7,] 31.34144 -15.76561
 [8,] 31.52396 -15.58309
 [9,] 31.73182 -15.39782
[10,] 31.95565 -15.21917
[11,] 32.17287 -15.02455

, , Frame002.txt

          [,1]      [,2]
 [1,] 30.13947 -16.92239
 [2,] 30.34071 -16.72115
 [3,] 30.53260 -16.52926
 [4,] 30.72348 -16.33496
 [5,] 30.92572 -16.13614
 [6,] 31.13358 -15.95087
 [7,] 31.34144 -15.76561
 [8,] 31.52396 -15.58309
 [9,] 31.73182 -15.39782
[10,] 31.95565 -15.21917
[11,] 32.17287 -15.02455

, , Frame003.txt

          [,1]      [,2]
 [1,] 30.13947 -16.92239
 [2,] 30.34071 -16.72115
 [3,] 30.53260 -16.52926
 [4,] 30.72348 -16.33496
 [5,] 30.92572 -16.13614
 [6,] 31.13358 -15.95087
 [7,] 31.34144 -15.76561
 [8,] 31.52396 -15.58309
 [9,] 31.73182 -15.39782
[10,] 31.95565 -15.21917
[11,] 32.17287 -15.02455
```

And for each slice I am trying to calculate the distance between the points contained in row [1,] and row [11,] (the first and last points).

I have truly gotten nowhere with this (I've tried the dist function and the geomorph::interlmkdist function) so any help would be much appreciated. I most recently tried the usedist::dist_subset function but it showed the following error, 'Error in as.matrix(d)[idx, idx] : no 'dimnames' attribute for array'.

I've had success in using the distancePointToPoint function but have to manually input the values from rows [1,] and [11,] which given the extent of the array, is not ideal.

Ideally, I want to return an array that looks something like this:

```
,, Frame001.txt
[1] 2.781459

,, Frame002.txt
[1] 2.781459

,, Frame003.txt
[1] 2.781459

etc.
```

Thank you!

```r
dput(curve_array)
structure(c(30.1394716184822, 30.3407126170086, 30.5325951613319, 
30.7234753517486, 30.9257187041817, 31.1335771291367, 31.3414355540918, 
31.5239596442118, 31.7318180691669, 31.9556523747537, 32.172869253912, 
-16.9223869881883, -16.7211459896618, ...), dim = c(11L, 
2L, 47L), dimnames = list(NULL, NULL, c("Frame001.txt", "Frame002.txt", 
"Frame003.txt", "Frame004.txt", "Frame005.txt", "Frame006.txt", 
"Frame007.txt", "Frame008.txt", "Frame009.txt", "Frame010.txt", 
"Frame011.txt", "Frame012.txt", "Frame013.txt", "Frame014.txt", 
"Frame015.txt", "Frame016.txt", "Frame017.txt", "Frame018.txt", 
"Frame019.txt", "Frame020.txt", "Frame021.txt", "Frame022.txt", 
"Frame023.txt", "Frame024.txt", "Frame025.txt", "Frame026.txt", 
"Frame027.txt", "Frame028.txt", "Frame029.txt", "Frame030.txt", 
"Frame031.txt", "Frame032.txt", "Frame033.txt", "Frame034.txt", 
"Frame035.txt", "Frame036.txt", "Frame037.txt", "Frame038.txt", 
"Frame039.txt", "Frame040.txt", "Frame041.txt", "Frame042.txt", 
"Frame043.txt", "Frame044.txt", "Frame045.txt", "Frame046.txt", 
"Frame047.txt")))
```

Comment: please `dput(curve_array)` and copy/paste output

Comment: @RicVillalba I've included it in the post as it's too long for the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` along the third margin to apply the distance operation to each slice of your array. This is just a simple Euclidian distance function between the first and 11th rows. The output is a named vector:

```r
apply(curve_array, 3, function(x) sqrt((x[1, 1]-x[11, 1])^2 + (x[1, 2]-x[11, 2])^2))
#> Frame001.txt Frame002.txt Frame003.txt Frame004.txt Frame005.txt 
#>     2.781455     2.781455     2.781455     2.781455     2.668020 
#> Frame006.txt Frame007.txt Frame008.txt Frame009.txt Frame010.txt 
#>     2.548641     2.350681     2.121847     1.791864     1.446678 
#> Frame011.txt Frame012.txt Frame013.txt Frame014.txt Frame015.txt 
#>     1.192961     1.054892     1.074074     1.182647     1.403697 
#> Frame016.txt Frame017.txt Frame018.txt Frame019.txt Frame020.txt 
#>     1.644818     1.889481     2.036533     2.155975     2.240272 
#> Frame021.txt Frame022.txt Frame023.txt Frame024.txt Frame025.txt 
#>     2.380460     2.484956     2.530551     2.537903     2.557738 
#> Frame026.txt Frame027.txt Frame028.txt Frame029.txt Frame030.txt 
#>     2.580983     2.659684     2.638101     2.697796     2.698458 
#> Frame031.txt Frame032.txt Frame033.txt Frame034.txt Frame035.txt 
#>     2.700066     2.693820     2.727060     2.718718     2.631126 
#> Frame036.txt Frame037.txt Frame038.txt Frame039.txt Frame040.txt 
#>     2.702522     2.744878     2.787322     2.758420     2.801023 
#> Frame041.txt Frame042.txt Frame043.txt Frame044.txt Frame045.txt 
#>     2.772264     2.772264     2.793633     2.750915     2.686989 
#> Frame046.txt Frame047.txt 
#>     2.715900     2.665723
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "distance"? Given your values I am guessing that these are geographic coordinates, and that you want geographic distance on a spheroid, not Euclidean distance.

If so, you could get the distance between the first and 11th row for one matrix like this

```
library(geosphere)
distGeo(curve_array[1,,1], curve_array[11,,1])
[1] 302457.3
```

Assuming that the data are in longitude(x)/latitude(y) order, and not the other way around!

And for the whole lot like this

```
a <- apply(curve_array, 3, \(m) distGeo(m[1,], m[11,]))

head(a)
#Frame001.txt Frame002.txt Frame003.txt Frame004.txt Frame005.txt Frame006.txt 
#    302457.3     302457.3     302457.3     302457.3     290466.7     278119.9
```

For Euclidean distance you could use

```
b <- apply(curve_array, 3, \(m) dist(m[c(1,11), ]))
head(b)
#Frame001.txt Frame002.txt Frame003.txt Frame004.txt Frame005.txt Frame006.txt 
#    2.781455     2.781455     2.781455     2.781455     2.668020     2.548641
```

Which is the same result as in Allan Cameron's answer

Comment: And just to mention that `\(m)` is equivalent to `function(m)`

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. In this case I did want Euclidean distance, but still great to see how geographical distance can be calculated :)

Answer (score 1):

With some subsetting `apply()` works well with `dist()` too:

```r
apply(curve_array[c(1,11),,], 3, dist)
#> Frame001.txt Frame002.txt Frame003.txt Frame004.txt Frame005.txt Frame006.txt 
#>     2.781455     2.781455     2.781455     2.781455     2.668020     2.548641 
#> Frame007.txt Frame008.txt Frame009.txt Frame010.txt Frame011.txt Frame012.txt 
#>     2.350681     2.121847     1.791864     1.446678     1.192961     1.054892 
#> Frame013.txt Frame014.txt Frame015.txt Frame016.txt Frame017.txt Frame018.txt 
#>     1.074074     1.182647     1.403697     1.644818     1.889481     2.036533 
#> Frame019.txt Frame020.txt Frame021.txt Frame022.txt Frame023.txt Frame024.txt 
#>     2.155975     2.240272     2.380460     2.484956     2.530551     2.537903 
#> Frame025.txt Frame026.txt Frame027.txt Frame028.txt Frame029.txt Frame030.txt 
#>     2.557738     2.580983     2.659684     2.638101     2.697796     2.698458 
#> Frame031.txt Frame032.txt Frame033.txt Frame034.txt Frame035.txt Frame036.txt 
#>     2.700066     2.693820     2.727060     2.718718     2.631126     2.702522 
#> Frame037.txt Frame038.txt Frame039.txt Frame040.txt Frame041.txt Frame042.txt 
#>     2.744878     2.787322     2.758420     2.801023     2.772264     2.772264 
#> Frame043.txt Frame044.txt Frame045.txt Frame046.txt Frame047.txt 
#>     2.793633     2.750915     2.686989     2.715900     2.665723
```